# How to replace all visible text by text with tags

Tags: java, android

I need to put every visible in browser word of html to shell like this:

source:

```
<p><strong> My source sentence</strong></p>
```

goal:

```
<p><strong><span>My </span><span>source </span><span>sentence</span></strong></p>
```

But do not touch any tags, javascripts and etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can extract the text, then use `replace` on each word, and replace it by itself with the tags you want surrounding it. i.e. `str = str.replace(str, "<span>" + str + "</span">);`.

Comment: I tried this way (with Jsoup) but if I have a letter "a" in text, replace "a" in whole doc crashes document. I need way to replace only text side, and it is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With no disrespect, but this looks like a dumb thing to do. But in any case, you can try to parse the the HTML (as parsing the XML, using a library) then replace every line with the new line.

Comment: Yes, I got text by parsing with jsoup. But how  to insert correctly target text back?

Comment: I haven't used parsers to be honest, but generally, you want to loop through all the content, and for every content that has value, take the string, split it over the spaces, add the two <span> and </spam> surrounding each word, then re-place it back.

Answer (score 0):

If your source is valid XML then it should be fairly easy to write a SAX handler to read the source in and output it the way you want, have a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html).

Essentially each time you come across an element you just output the element to the output stream. Each time you come across some text just use a regular expression (or similar) to split it into the parts your want and wrap each part in a span element. This seems like a really strange thing to do though.

If your input source isn't valid XML (if it's HTML with all the various things that can be broken with that) then it's going to be much harder unless you can first transform the source into valid XML.

Comment: It is html. With tables, images and so on.

Comment: In that case have a look at this library: http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/ it will clean up the HTML you will be loading and processing but you have to keep in mind that it can't work miracles and you'll probably hit files that won't load correctly.